# How can I set command line arugment in github action?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions

My aim is to create github workflow for publishing the plugin. Here I have to enter some command line arguments after executing some command. Can someone please tell me, whether there is a way to set the command line arguments in github action ?

Comment: If the below answer helped have you considered accepting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you're trying to build your GitHub Action and don't know how to pass arguments to it, correct? If so, you can use `inputs` mechanism to pass arguments to your action. For example:

#### JavaScript Action

action.yml

```yaml
...
inputs:
  version:
    description: Plugin version
    required: true
runs:
  using: 'node12'
  main: index.js
...
```

index.js

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const version = core.getInput('version');
```

#### Docker Action

action.yml

```yaml
...
inputs:
  version:
    description: Plugin version
    required: true
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.version }}
...
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh -l
echo $1 # your version
```

#### Usage:

workflow.yml

```yaml
...
steps:
  name: Your action usage
  uses: mysuperaction@master
  with:
    version: 1
...
```